# UICollectionView Cells are not side by side

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell

I have UICollectionView 2 line cells.
 As long as the text in the length of the cells but cells are not side by side.

I have UICollectionView 2 line cells.
 As long as the text in the length of the cells but cells are not side by side.

[image]

How fix that.

Here is my code.

```
    let musicType = ["Blues", "Klasik", "Halk", "Hip-hop", "Caz", "Pop", "Rock", " Enstrümantal", "House", "Rap" , "Slow"]

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return musicType.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = musicType[indexPath.item]
        cell.sizeToFit()
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
       // let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell

        let text = NSAttributedString(string: musicType[indexPath.item])
        print(musicType[indexPath.item])
        print(" - ")
        print(text.size())

        let width = (text.size().width) * 2
        let height = CGFloat(40)
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)

    }



}

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
       let lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return lbl
    }()


    func setupView(){
        backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        addSubview(nameLabel)
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": nameLabel]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": nameLabel]))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

Comment: Now, how u r getting? One by One or side by side [as in ur question's screenshot] ??

Answer (score 0):

Add this method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Comment: I have already 

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: CGFloat(screen.widthHesap(x: 449)), left: 0, bottom: CGFloat(screen.heightHesap(x: 108)), right: CGFloat(screen.widthHesap(x: 150)))
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10

Comment: Than you shouldn't use UICollectionViewFlowLayout. Try to use custom layout like https://github.com/mokagio/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout

Comment: Do you have anything for Swift

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to add "override" to the setUpViews() function:

```
 class BaseCell: UICollectionViewCell {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setUpViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

}


func setUpViews() {
    backgroundColor = .blue

}

}
class FriendCell: BaseCell {

     override func setUpViews() {

        addSubview(profileImageView)
        addSubview(dividerLineView)

        setUpContainerView()

        profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "boy.png")


        addConstraintsWithformat(format: "H:|-12-[v0(68)]", views: profileImageView)
        addConstraintsWithformat(format: "V:[v0(68)]", views: profileImageView)

        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: profileImageView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

        addConstraintsWithformat(format: "H:|-82-[v0]|", views: dividerLineView)
        addConstraintsWithformat(format: "V:[v0(1)]|", views: dividerLineView)
```

}

And Add something like this to try it out :

```
private func setUpContainerView() {
        let containerView = UIView()
        addSubview(containerView)

        addConstraintsWithformat(format: "H:|-90-[v0]|", views: containerView)
        addConstraintsWithformat(format: "V:[v0(50)]|", views: containerView)
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))



    }
```

Comment: I am try but i get error -- 

Method does not override any method from its superclass

Comment: First you'll need to create a class the inherits from UICollectionViewCell and add the setUpViews() function. Then you want to use that "BaseCell" to be the superclass of the cells you're displaying. That way you can override the setUpViews() Function. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Okay.... I added a little bit more code. Try to add a UIView to the contents of the cell and then edit those constraints first. This was done with the setUpContainerView() Function.

Comment: Full example and code here https://www.letsbuildthatapp.com/course/Facebook-Chat-Messenger

Answer (score 0):

Please use custom layout for align collectionview cell

use below library :: https://github.com/mokagio/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout

setting collection view layout with below code

```
    let layout = UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout.init()
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```